# How can I resize the image to fit the picturebox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to resize the image to fit the PictureBox size but it's not working.
I added a method `resizeImage` but no matter what size I give the result is the same.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap myBitmap = CreateNonIndexedImage(new Bitmap(@"d:\drawplane1.jpg"));
        resizeImage(myBitmap, new Size(1, 1));

        // Draw myBitmap to the screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmap.Width,
            myBitmap.Height);

        // Set each pixel in myBitmap to black.
        for (int Xcount = 0; Xcount < myBitmap.Width; Xcount++)
        {
            for (int Ycount = 0; Ycount < myBitmap.Height; Ycount++)
            {
                myBitmap.SetPixel(Xcount, Ycount, Color.Black);
            }
        }

        // Draw myBitmap to the screen again.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, myBitmap.Width, 0,
            myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height);
    }

    public Bitmap CreateNonIndexedImage(Image src)
    {
        Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp))
        {
            gfx.DrawImage(src, 0, 0);
        }

        return newBmp;
    }

    public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
    }
}
```

No mater what size I put in the line:

```
resizeImage(myBitmap, new Size(1, 1));
```

..the image is too big inside the pictureBox:
I tried `10,10` then `1,1` for testing but it's not changing the image size.

[image: Image in picturebox]

This is the original image :

[image: Original]

Original image file : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uFMo.jpg

Comment: Is that the back of the Eurofighter?

Comment: If this is just for displaying the image, you don't need to resize the image. The `PictureBox` control gives you control over this out of the box. Use `pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom`. You may also use `PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage` if you like but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fit Image into PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822138/fit-image-into-picturebox)

Comment: Nothing with the sizemode is working. I tried in the code and in the editor properties but nothing changed.

Comment: Could be the method CreateNonIndexedImage make something wrong ?

Comment: See the `ResizeImage()` method here: [How to crop an elliptical region of an Image with smooth borders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61554272/7444103) and all the related methods here: [Zoom and translate an Image from the mouse location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61964222/7444103) (where you can find all you actually need: `GetScaledRect()`, `GetDrawingImageRect()`, `CenterScaledRectangleOnCanvas()`, etc.). The notes here: [Disable Image blending on a PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54726707/7444103) can also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

- You don't use the `SizeMode` property
- You draw the image in the `Paint` event instead of just setting the `Image` property

If you want to draw the image in `Paint` (eg. because it is an animation, whose frames are generated rapidly), then you don't need a `PictureBox`, a simple `Panel` will also do it.

But if you generate the image once, then just assign it to the `Image` property, set the `SizeMode` for scaling and `PictureBox` will care about the rest

Comment: If you're drawing an animated sequence, you really don't want to use a Panel. A PictureBox is way better, since it's double-buffered. If you want a *lighter* control, a Flat Label is also double-buffered. `Panel` is not.

Comment: Double buffering can be enabled for any control.

Comment: Double-buffering can be enabled but a Control as a PictureBox and its internal operations cannot be emulated. Thus, it's not the same thing. I don't see a reason to do that either, since you already have a Control with these features setup and optimized. If one needs a drawing surface with less dependencies, as already mentioned, the Label Control offers the same functionality without any modifications. Some, for unknown reasons, thinks that a PictureBox is *heavier* than a Panel (not considering the Label at all, of course): that's mythology.

Comment: PictureBox derives from Control, Panel from `ScrollableControl` and implements `IArrangedElement`: not exactly made for drawing (even though enabling its `OptimizedDoubleBuffer` can be used to create *special effects*, as shown here: [Transparent Overlapping Circular Progress Bars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53379442/7444103), for example (because if generates a form of *persistence* in its DC), but *less heavy* (whatever that can mean here), not really.

Comment: Look, you are right in all of these, but the point wasn't that `Panel` is the _one right choice_ for drawing in `OnPaint` but rather that it has nothing to do with `PictureBox`. And scrolling can be actually useful when you implement custom zooming. However, even my custom zoomable/scrollable [image viewer](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing.Tools/blob/5c6d214def68b1e4efd1827f0aa2992ef7f92f1b/KGySoft.Drawing.ImagingTools/View/Controls/ImageViewer.cs#L37) is derived (almost) directly from `Control` but that is another story.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `SizeMode` of your `PictureBox` to `PictureSizeMode.Zoom` or `PictureSizeMode.StretchImage` and see if it helps. Either through your properties editor or in code.

```
 pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SizeMode property of PictureBox from Properties window and set its value to StrechImage

[image]