# C# Visual Studio Picture FIlter Mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, picturebox, scaling

How does one change filtermode for a specific image in VS2013?

I'm using the PictureBox component with zoom sizemode but it scales the image
bilineary and since the image I'm using is a low resolution sprite (32px*32px) i'd like to have it use Neareset Point filtering instead.

Comment: Could this be helpful to you? [Link: How do I make a PictureBox use Nearest Neighbor resampling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29157/how-do-i-make-a-picturebox-use-nearest-neighbor-resampling)

Comment: PictureBox doesn't let you set the Graphics.InterpolationMode property value that it uses.  Simple workaround is to *not* set its Image property but write an event handler for its Paint event instead.  Beware that implementing the SizeMode property is also your job now.